# Identity Toolkit API config returns "CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-api, google-identity-toolkit

I am trying to enable `Firebase Authentication` in my project, and to add `Phone Auth` to it, via API (without using the GUI console).

I am using the `Service Usage API` in order to enable `Identity Toolkit`, and then trying to use `Identity Toolkit API` in order to add the `Phone Auth`.

I am enabling `Identity Toolkit` via the `Service Usage API` like this (POST request):

**URL**:

```
https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/MY_GCP_PROJ/services:batchEnable
```

**Body**:

```
{
  "serviceIds": ["identitytoolkit"]
}
```

And indeed, after running this request I see in GCP console that `Identity Toolkit` has been enabled.

After that, I try to update the config using `Identity Toolkit API`, like this (PATCH request):

**URL**:

```
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v2/projects/MY_GCP_PROJ/config?updateMask=signIn
```

**Body**:

```
{
    "signIn": {
        "phoneNumber": {
            "enabled": true,
            "testPhoneNumbers": {
                "+11111111111": "123456",
            }
        },
    }
}
```

But for some reason, I receive an error saying:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND",
        "status": "NOT_FOUND"
    }
}
```

I can't understand why the `Identity Toolkit API` cannot find the configuration and update it as specified.

Does anyone know how it can be solved?

Thank you

Comment: From experience, it's a little gnarly. Have you tried `GET`'ting `/config` to confirm that your mask matches the structure? What identity are you using to auth the requests?

Comment: @DazWilkin Yes, I did try to `GET`, but unfortunately I get the same error. I use the bearer token to auth the request. When I enabled Identity Provider manually via the GCP console, the request suddenly started working. But it's still not a solution for me as I want to automate this process and enable it via the REST API. Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: Which identity? Your user account (`you@gmail.com`)? That won't work. You will need to create a Service Account. I [blogged](https://pretired.dazwilkin.com/posts/211026/) about my experience with this (adding authorized domains for Firebase Auth). I'm headed out for the afternoon|evening but will check in on this tomorrow to see how you're doing.

Comment: @DazWilkin Thank you. I've re-tried with a service account token of GCP, but I still get the `CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND` error unfortunately. Did you find a way to solve it?

Comment: It works for me (updating `authorizedDomains`). Are you able to get `GET /config`? If the auth's working, I suspect your `updateMask` or body are incorrect

Comment: @DazWilkin Unfortunately, I am unable to `GET` the config as well. Same error. It works for me only after I manually enable `Identity Provider` in the project. Does it work for you without enabling it manually?

Comment: You **must** enable the service in the project before you'll be able to invoke its methods. `gcloud services enable identitytoolkit.googleapis.com --project=${PROJECT}`

Comment: @DazWilkin I did enable `identitytoolkit.googleapis.com`. But it doesn't work. It only works when I enable `Identity Platform` manually through the console

Comment: My experience differs from yours. Google's various (!) identity services are confusing to me. For `authorizedDomains`, I used `identitytoolkit` with the `GET` and `PATCH` on `/config`. If I have time tomorrow, I'll try to reproduce your experience.

Comment: @DazWilkin Thank you. If you try to reproduce it, please try it with a brand new GCP/Firebase project. Maybe that's related. I am creating the project using the `firebase projects:create -o $GCLOUD_ORGANISATION_ID -n "$NAME" $NEW_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID` command of the Firebase CLI

Comment: @DazWilkin I've started a bounty for this question, if you want to contribute :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent days config Firebase Auth without using Web UI :).
Even checking the GCP audit log to see what backend call enables Firebase Auth.

[image]

However, I could not find the CreateConfig method at https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest.

I tried this method and things work.
https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.identityPlatform/initializeAuth

```
curl --request POST \
  --url "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v2/projects/$ENV_GCP_PROJECT_ID/identityPlatform:initializeAuth" \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header "X-Goog-User-Project: $ENV_GCP_PROJECT_ID"
```

But the result is the new Identity Platform will be used instead of the old Identity Toolkit.

Looking at pricing, it seems (a bit) more expensive https://firebase.google.com/pricing.
I personally will use the new one (as Google is pushing it :).
Hope this answer somehow helps (or anyone can find the REST call to enable auth for the old Identity Toolkit)

Answer (score -1):

The same issue happened to me when I was trying to use REST API but then I get to know that the URL I am using was wrong.
Try [Method: projects.updateConfig](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/updateConfig)

Comment: This is exactly the URL I was using, which gave me the error mentioned above. Did you manage to enable the Authentication feature on a new Firebase/GCP project using this endpoint?